# Android lan wifi connectivity

Tags: android, http, networking, httpurlconnection

This may be a design issue but I would like to know anyway.

Example: I have a data connection and also have a wifi connection to my local network on my android device/phone.  I want to access **deviceB** on my local network.

IF: My local network gateway has a connection to the outside world my android device **can** access **deviceB**.  external connections work just fine.

IF: my local network gateway does not have a connection to the outside world my android device **can not** access **deviceB**.  external connections work just fine.

**deviceB** for this example is a local webserver http://{localipaddress}

**EDITED:**

LAN IP range 10.1.1/

deviceB addr: 10.1.1.154

android wifi addr: 10.1.1.111

I have also tried simply just using a browser(chrome) on my android phone with same result

```
12-04 16:46:54.370 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave D/isReachable: Connection to 10.1.1.154 failed
12-04 16:46:54.371 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:484)
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:135)
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
12-04 16:46:54.392 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:150)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:325)
12-04 16:46:54.393 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:193)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.linuxjet.apps.agave.Tools.isReachable(Tools.java:299)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.linuxjet.apps.agave.services.ConnectionService.rebuildISY(ConnectionService.java:107)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at com.linuxjet.apps.agave.services.ConnectionService.onHandleIntent(ConnectionService.java:91)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-04 16:46:54.394 30997-31204/com.linuxjet.apps.agave W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Here is my code that I use to test connection:

```
public static boolean isReachable(String host, int port, int timeout, Boolean ssl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
      url = new URL((ssl ? "https://" : "http://") + host+":"+port);
        //open a connection to that source
      HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
      HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      if (ssl) {
        TrustAllSSLSocketFactory sslfactory;
        try {
          sslfactory = new TrustAllSSLSocketFactory();
          ((HttpsURLConnection) urlConnect).setSSLSocketFactory(sslfactory);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      urlConnect.setReadTimeout(timeout);
      urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
      urlConnect.setRequestMethod("GET");
      urlConnect.setDoInput(true);
      urlConnect.connect();
      urlConnect.getContent();
      urlConnect.disconnect();
      Log.d("isReachable","Connection to " + url.getHost() + " succeeded");
      return true;
      //trying to retrieve data from the source. If there
      //is no connection, this line will fail
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.d("isReachable", "Connection to " + url.getHost() + " failed");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should exactly tell which ip address you use. So what are you using for parameter host?

Comment: ' with same result'. But what is that result? You did not tell which message/error/exception you get.

Comment: updated with additional information

Comment: You have a SocketTimeoutException. You said that Chrome delivered the same result. But is it?  Did you use 10.1.1.154 for parameter host? I asked that info before.

Comment: You don't need to reply with the obvious.  I know I am getting a timeout exception.  I wan to know why it happens only when the my gateway has no  outside connection to the world.  Yes, 10.1.1.154 is always the intended host for this specific purpose of this conversation.